# Connection errors on hack the box and vulnhub (Kali, virtual box)

Tags: network, kali-linux

Ill start by show my attacking machine network setup:
[image]

When trying to do a box on HTB or Vulnhub, I am *sometimes* able to ping it (nmap -Pn). Once I am able to ping a machine, I do a full nmap scan. Next, for example, if a box has a webserver running I start dirbuster. Dirbuster times out due to 20 consecutive errors and throws these errors in the terminal, where 192.168.1.184 is the FristiLeaks vulnhub machine but the same error occurs when doing HTB and scanning a webserver:
[image]
Then I am unable to ping or scan the target host (host unreachable or unresponsive).

FristiLeaks lab setup:
[image]

Additionally, here are the contents of my /etc/hosts file if relevant:
[image]

I just started the VIP services on HTB. I have tried regenerating, downloading another connection pack, and switching servers but the same connection error above happens on any HTB or Vulnhub lab box.

Maybe it has something to do with what ifconfig displays or lack-thereof? Lastly, I just passed the eCPPT certification which required openvpn and I experienced no connection issues before or during the exam.

Comment: This does look like  a network problem and not an information security problem, i.e. off-topic here. Note that not everything becomes magically an information security problem just because you are using Kali.

Comment: I tagged "Kali" and "Network" because that made the most sense. Where should I direct this thread?

Comment: Try superuser.com instead.